# Userscript to click "Show more..." button on YouTube using TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to click a "show more" button on Youtube users page using Tampermonkey.Also already researched here on the site but found no satisfactory answer to my case.

Html of the buttons:

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button" type="button" onclick=";return false;" aria-label="Carregar mais
" data-uix-load-more-href="/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&amp;continuation=4qmFsgJAEhhVQ2UwSXlLNG50Z2RQVFRqc3hqdnlIUGcaJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk1yZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D" data-uix-load-more-target-id="channels-browse-content-grid"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">  <span class="load-more-loading hid">
      <span class="yt-spinner">
      <span title="Carregando ícone" class="yt-spinner-img  yt-sprite"></span>

Carregando...
  </span>

  </span>
  <span class="load-more-text">
    Carregar mais

  </span>
</span></button>
```

I first tried this code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/user/*/videos
// @grant        none
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(
   $(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button")[0].click();
});
);
```

And also i tried this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/user/*/videos
// @grant        none
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(        

    setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('#yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button').click()
}, 1000)
```

But both codes seems to not work at all. Could someone give me an explanation to how to fix that? what code i have to put there? i know nothing about JS.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 20th of Feb 2018, the URLs you're matching to (`https://www.youtube.com/user/*/videos`) actually return HTML pages that rely on infinite scrolling. There is no "Show More" HTML button as you have mentioned. This means:

```
document.querySelector('#yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button');
```

will return `null`, and when you perform a `.click()` you'll just get a TypeError. Clearly, not what you're wanting.

If you are wanting to "Show More" videos on the page using Javascript, you have to do this instead:

```
document.querySelector("yt-next-continuation").trigger();
```